# Laravel 5 Easy way to get the id of the record selected with a slug

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to find a easy way to get the id of a record (selected with a slug) so I can use it to query the children of this record (parent/child related).

```
$product = Products::where('url','the-slug')->get();
```

Now I can use the collection to get the id and go on with querying the children.

Is there a easier way to do this?

**And...**

Can I query the children by slug alone?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of `first()->id` you should use the `pluck()` method:

```
$productId = Products::where('url', 'the-slug')->pluck('id');
```

The advantage of `pluck()` is that if no product is found it will return `null` whereas `first()->id` will produce an error because `first()` returns `null` and you can't access a property of a non-object.

---

As an alternative you could use `firstOrFail` to throw an `ModelNotFoundException` when no row matches your condition:

```
$productId = Products::where('url', 'the-slug')->firstOrFail()->id;
```

---

You could also just do the checking yourself of course:

```
$product = Products::where('url', 'the-slug')->first();
if($product !== null){
    // product found, proceed
}
```

Comment: Agree. Better safe then sorry. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter ! The problem is that pluck returns an array of results. And that's why I think is more straight foward to use ->first()->id if theres only one matching result

Answer (score 3):

```php
$productId = Products::where('url', 'the-slug')->first()->id;
```

Comment: Laravel keeps suprising me. As do you with this simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Klaaz absolutely agree with you, Laravel is just awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This function gives you products you are looking for...

```
function findByProductId() {
    $productId = Products::where('url', 'the-slug')
                           ->pluck('id');
}
return $productId;
```